# How to get per 1000 deaths numbers for the 1932-34 Holodomor in Ukraine for the rural areas only, against the less starving town population?

Tags: soviet-union, ukraine, famine

As to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holodomor), Holodomor is about:

- Country: Ukrainian Soviet Socialist Republic, Soviet Union
  Location: Central and eastern Ukraine
  Period: 1932–1933
- Total deaths: Around 3.5 million

And

[image: ![enter image description here]

Source: https://gis.huri.harvard.edu/population-losses

How many of these Holodomor excess deaths were in rural areas and which rural Holodomor excess deaths per 1000 would then be the numbers for each region and overall? How does this look for the urban deaths?

On region level, with the large town populations, the numbers are already high, they must be much higher in the rural areas then than in the towns.

Comment: Which deaths are you referring to when you ask "How many of these deaths were in rural areas", the regional death tolls from the table or for the country as a whole?

Comment: @SteveBird I meant the per 1000 excess deaths so that it is comparable. The absolute deaths in the left column are not meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the source of this table, [Ukrainian Research Institute, Harvard University](https://gis.huri.harvard.edu/population-losses), and found at first that there was no per 1000 map of the deaths of *only* the rural population although the overall percentage is known *(which was a wrong finding, I found that map later in the same source, see at the bottom)*:

> 4 percent of the urban and 16 percent of the rural population in 1933.

[image]

## Full quote of the source

> Map of Total Direct Famine Losses in Ukraine by Region, 1932-1934
> Overview
>
> This map shows absolute numbers of excess deaths in Ukraine's seven
> oblasts and the Autonomous Moldavian Socialist Soviet Republic
> (Moldavia). The shading of each region represents the total number of
> excess deaths during 1932-1934, while the bar charts in each region
> represent annual excess deaths. Numbers of excess deaths for 1932-1934
> are divided into three intervals, depicted by three different
> color-scale shades, and the number for each region is shown on the
> map.
>
> The total number of 1932-1934 famine losses in Soviet Ukraine is
> estimated at 4.5 million, with 3.9 million direct losses (excess
> deaths) and 0.6 million indirect losses (lost births). The 1933
> midyear population of Ukraine is estimated at 29.6 million. The 3.9
> million direct losses are approximately equivalent to 13 percent of
> the total population in 1933. The 3.9 million is composed of 0.3
> million in urban areas and 3.6 million in rural areas; these numbers
> are approximately equivalent to 4 percent of the urban and 16 percent
> of the rural population in 1933. It is important to note that the
> Holodomor is commonly understood as occurring in the period 1932-1933.
> However, the analysis here shows that significant famine-related
> losses also occurred in 1934. This is the first time that regional
> estimates of direct losses have been made for Ukraine.

## Full source information, again quoted from the source

> Sources
>
> This map visualizes data based on estimates of deaths during the
> Holodomor period derived under the "Estimation of Regional Losses of
> the 1932-1934 Famine in Ukraine" project conducted by Oleh Wolowyna
> (University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill) and Omelian Rudnytskyi,
> Nataliia Levchuk, Pavlo Shevchuk, and Alla Kovbasiuk (Institute of
> Demography and Social Studies in Kyiv).
>
> The estimation here of Holodomor losses is based on separate yearly
> urban and rural population reconstructions by age and sex, using data
> from three Soviet censuses (1926, 1937, and 1939), as well as annual
> vital statistics and migration data for the 1927-1939 period. 1926 and
> 1937 census data were adjusted for undercounts and other problems,
> while 1939 census data were adjusted to eliminate falsifications
> implemented to cover up large population losses understood to be due
> to the famine and other repressive policies. Yearly registered births
> and deaths were adjusted for undercounts, especially during famine
> years when the undercount reached extreme levels. Based on these data
> and detailed data on migration, taking into account urban-rural
> reclassification, yearly population figures were reconstructed
> according to age and sex for Soviet Ukraine's eight regions, as well
> as for urban-rural areas.

## Raw calculation

One could calculate this for the whole rural areas:

> The 3.9 million is composed of 0.3 million in urban areas and 3.6 million in rural areas; these numbers are approximately equivalent to 4 percent of the urban and 16 percent of the rural population in 1933.

With the also said 29.6 Mio population, with the share of 3.6/3.9=92.3% in rural deaths, the sum of "Total Deaths (1932–1934 in thousands)" is 3942.5. Then (own calculation):

[image]

full population:

[image]

and rural population:

[image]

and town population:

[image]

So that on the whole, the Holodomor excess deaths per 1000 were:

- 161.7 (rural)
- 40.4 (town)

## Helpful maps

There are maps on rural and urban splits of Holodomor excess deaths per 1000 in the same source:

[image]

[image]

You can find more maps about 1932, 1933 and 1934 region levels there as well and other maps, but the main thing is that the rural population had to suffer much more than the urban population, rural range from roughly 100 to 500 while urban from 10 to 100 (very roughly, just looking at the colours). I do not have enough reputation to post more than the eight links here, have a look at the absolute number maps on the website.

Comment: Is this intended as a answer or as an extension of the question? Also you should use the quotation markup to show which parts of this are lifted from the Harvard article.

Comment: @SteveBird I am still working on it, sorry. I had it first in a question, but then found the maps on rural / urban split only in the end to split it into question and answer.